# How to fix "largeNumber^5+1 = largeNumber^5" in Java

Tags: java, bignum

I am searching for a, b, and c such that a^5+b^5 = c^5. My program yields 2000^5+1= 2000^5. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

```
public class Euler {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        long i=0;
        int power = 5;
        int a1 = 1; 
        int a2 = 2000;

        boolean isSolved = false;
        long sumOfPowers = 0;
        double root = 0;
        long roundDown = 0;
        long roundDown2Power = 0;

            sumOfPowers = (long) (Math.pow(a1, power) + Math.pow(a2, power));
            root = Math.pow(sumOfPowers, 1.0/power);

            roundDown = (long) root;
            roundDown2Power = (long)Math.pow(roundDown, power);

            if (sumOfPowers == roundDown2Power) {
                isSolved = true;
                System.out.println(isSolved + " " + a1 + "^" + power + " + " + a2 + "^" + power + " + "  + "^" + power +  " = " + roundDown + "^" + power );
            }
        }
    }
```

---

I am searching for counterexamples of Euler's conjecture. I was successful for fifth power using this method [An error searching for a counterexample to Euler's conjecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034546/an-error-searching-for-a-counterexample-to-eulers-conjecture)
27^5 + 84^5 + 110^5 + 133^5 = 144^5 (Lander & Parkin, 1966), it takes 6 seconds. I am trying to get 5800^4 + 217519^4 + 414560^4 = 422481^4 (Roger Frye, 1988), but when testing this module I find that my program yields 2000^5+1=2000^5. Which is a problem.

Comment: Are you aware of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem ?

Comment: Sure, I know. I am trying to find a counterexample to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture and I have it working for n=5, but I can't make it work for n=4 because due to rounding errors `20k^4+1=20k^4`.

Comment: The primitive types have a limited range of values that can be represented and in case of float/double the accuracy a value can be represented with is also limited (for integer values above n>2^52  the expression n==n+1 becomes *true*). You will need to switch to using an arbitrary precision type like e.g. BigInteger to overcome these limitations (expect a notable dip in performance, though).

Comment: BigInteger doesn't have a method to calculate roots out of the box.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should try to use BigInteger lib in Java.

Comment: That does not answer the *"why"*. And please elaborate more. (not the downvoter)

Comment: To get back on track @John - your answer is of very low quality. Since you did not fix that situation until now you *now* got a downvote from me too. Just shouting out a buzz word might be of help for OP but that still leaves a bad answer. Include some explanation what OP did wrong initially and how that situation can be changed by using a `BigInteger`.

Comment: @luk2302  why don't you write a good answer yourself? Just to provide an example?

Comment: @sixtytrees because that is not what I am here for - I am / was here to moderate! I am not trying to get points or post answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a mismatch of what the types long and double can do (and are precisely defined to do) and your purely mathematical view of the equations.

The primitive types have a limited range of values that can be represented. Thats whats tripping up your calculations. The long can represent values in range Long.MAX_VALUE (2^63-1) and Long.MIN_VALUE -(2^63). The double type can represent a larger range *but at the cost of accuracy*. Integers represented as doubles are only accurately representable up to 2^52, above the least significant (binary) digits are dropped. Thats all because these types have a fixed size of 64 bits in memory and its impossible to represents more than 2^64 states in those bits.

The solution for your problem is not to use those types but an arbitrary precision type that can represent large number exactly without truncation or rounding. There are the BigInteger and BigDecimal classes for this purpose. Note that BigDecimal will *still* round (e.g. you cannot represent 1/3 with it), only you can select where to round.

Also these are object types, meaning you cannot write equations, you'll have to call their methods to perform operations with them. The available operations are also somewhat limited, requiring some problems to be rearranged to be solved.

Edit: There is nothing java specific about the behavior of the types long and double, you would have the exact same problems in *any* language that provides you with the same types. Double behavior is a specified standard (IEEE-754), longs properties are dictated by twos-complement rules (and its size of 64 bits).

Comment: I got it from John's comment. How do I work with BigInteger? I tried `BigInteger a = 1;` but it doesn't compile.

Comment: @sixtytrees As i wrote you have to call their methods, not writing equations, there is the javadoc that documents it. If that isnt enough, a simple search would find you example code like this: http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=13193